# RegEx - Exclude char sequence from matches

Tags: java, regex

I'm struggling with a RegEx, and I hope to find some guidance here. I already searched here and on Google, but it's hard for me to find the right terms. I could image that non-capturing groups would help me, but I don't know how to apply them.

Basically I want to **find Java single line comments, which are "screaming"** (no lower case letters):

```
^[ \t]*//[^a-z]+?$
```

Now I also find comments like these:

```
// PN-123456 
// ITK 12345
//IT-12345
```

**These comments are valid** for me, so I wanted to **exclude them from the RegEx above**. It's always this pattern:

1. Optional whitespace
2. "PN" or "IT" or "ITK"
3. Hyphen, whitespace or nothing
4. Four to six digits
5. Optional whitespace

That's my approach for this pattern:

```
[ ]?PN[ -]?[0-9]{1,6}
```

But now I just can't unite both expressions in one RegEx. How would this work?

TIA,
Peter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^//(?!\s*(?:PN|ITK?)[ -]?[0-9]{1,6}[ ]*$)[^a-z]+?$
```

Note that `[^a-z]+` requires there would be not lower case letters, but isn't quite the same as "only upper case". For example, it will catch the comment `// ----------`, and even an empty `//` (as long as there's a space).

Example: http://regexr.com?31app

Comment: That's it, perfect! And yes, I also wanted to include "non-sense comments", which e.g. are empty or so. Please allow that I adapt your proposal to meet exactly the example I gave (the negative lookahead should include " //"). Still, that's great. Thank you very much :-) I will have a look in the lookahead topic for future use.

Comment: @Peter - I was just testing it and adding the `//` - it can go before the lookahead (it can also be `\s*//`, of course). Thanks!